# Call PHP Function using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've read all the topics about my question but cannot solve my problem. I want to get php function result using jQuery AJAX.

```js
function fetch_select(){
  val_name = $('#name').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
 url: 'include/get_db.inc.php',
 data: {
           name: val_name,
 },
 success: function (response) {
   document.getElementById('higtchart_medie_gen').innerHTML=response;
   columnChart( JSON.parse(response));
    }
  });
}

function columnChart(data_v){
  if(data_v.length >0){
    $(function () {
   $('#higtchart_medie_gen').highcharts({
     chart: {
    type: 'column'
   },
......
```

`#name` is id for select tag.
My code for get_db.inc.php is:

```html
<?php
function test_name () {
  $ret = [];
  if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $sql = "SELECT 
            ......
            WHERE ID = $name ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $ret [] = [$row['NAME'] . ' ' . $row['LASTN'], floatval($row['AVGG'])];
      }
    }
  }
  if(count($ret) >1) echo json_encode($ret);
  else echo 'Not working';
}
?>
```

How can I call *test_name* function from Ajax code?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I saw that post and many others. I'm running in circle for 4 days trying to solve this problem and i don't succed.

Answer (score 0):

You do almost correct but only one mistake is you forget to invoke the function. What you do is just send the data to this file.

So, to fixed this. Just add `test_name()` to your `get_db.inc.php`

```
 <?php
      function test_name () {
           $ret = [];
           if(isset($_POST['name'])){
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $sql = "SELECT 
                 ......
                WHERE ID = $name ";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                          $ret [] = [$row['NAME'] . ' ' . $row['LASTN'],floatval($row['AVGG'])];
                     }
                }
           }
          if(count($ret) >1) echo json_encode($ret);
          else echo 'Not working';
     }

     test_name()
 ?>
```

Also it will be better to check isset outside the function.

```
function test_name ($name) {
     $ret = [];
     $sql = "SELECT 
     ......
     WHERE ID = $name ";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     if($result->num_rows > 0){
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $ret [] = [$row['NAME'] . ' ' . $row['LASTN'],floatval($row['AVGG'])];
           }
     }
     if(count($ret) >1) echo json_encode($ret);
     else echo 'Not working';
}

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    test_name($_POST['name'])
}
```

This will make your function to be pure. It will easier to debug later and it will not invoke if you don't have `$_POST['name']`.

Comment: In my get_db.inc.php file will be more functions and i wanna indicate to the ajax code to call the function that i prefer.

Comment: You can try to put in your data in ajax a simple var like "action: value" and in your php make your test on this $_POST['action]